# WPF Multiple Buttons to Navigate multiple pages with one frame

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I have buttonA and buttonB. I have FrameA and Page1 Page2.

Question:

If I clicked buttonA how would I show Page1 through FrameA?

Then I clicked buttonB how would I show Page2 through FrameA?

Examples would be great (VB .net or c#)

Answer (score 0):

Assume you can add button click event and in that click event do the navigation as below

e.g : in buttonA click event :

```
FrameA.Navigate(myPage1Object);
```